# Call Fetch.Lazy list without instance

Tags: java, lazy-loading

Good colleagues,

I am collecting an Object from a @modelAttribute with the new data that has been modified. But when I try to collect a lazy list without instantiating it, it returns the exception. How can I call it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: When you fetch your Property entity you need to eagerly fetch the userAuthorizations to make them available once a session is closed

Comment: Make sure your transaction is still open with `@Transactional`

Comment: You need an active transaction + session to initialize lazy properties. Once the session is closed, hibernate can no longer initialize lazy properties